# How to backup the public folder of a laravel application?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, backup, public

I have many data in public folder in a laravel project which is deployed in cpanel, but is costing so much storage in server. I need to backup the public folder. Is there any system to keep backup of public folder of laravel project?
laravel 5.5

Comment: It's just a folder...you can back it up in the many normal ways you can backup any folder on a computer. It's unclear what the problem is, or how it relates to PHP programming. It sounds like an system administrator task. I'd probably advise you to back up your whole site though (and your database), not just one folder.

Comment: I just need the public folder. Because i had deploy a project in cpanel where every week many many file data is imported and day by day this is increasing. As a result those data in public folder is costing many storage. So i have to delete all public data after 6 months later and later. And I need to backup of public folder. Please help me brother.

Comment: Why do you assume everyone here is a "brother"? I'm not offended, but I strongly advise you to use neutral language or just refer to people by their usernames only, in case one day you find someone who _is_ offended. Programmers can be brothers, sisters, and probably aliens and fish too, for all I know. It's best not to make any assumptions.

Comment: Anyway what exactly do you need help with? As I already said, there are many many many ways to implement backups of folders on a server, which you could likely find with a simple google search. Where are you stuck? To be honest you should be backing up your whole site automatically as a matter of routine administration anyway. It's a bit scary if you aren't. The frequency is up to you, but daily or weekly as a minimum. If you're on a shared hosting environment you may find the hosting provider is actually doing this for you already, and you can maybe access the backups via cpanel.

Comment: Okay Thanks ADyson. I have to serch more. I hope, I will get my answer.

Answer (score 3):

you can use package `composer require spatie/laravel-backup`

then publish the config file to `config/backup.php.`

open `backup.php`

```
<?php
 
return [
 
        .......
 
        'source' => [
 
            'files' => [
 
                /*
                 * The list of directories and files that will be included in the backup.
                 */
                'include' => [
                    base_path(),
                ],
 
                /*
                 * These directories and files will be excluded from the backup.
                 *
                 * Directories used by the backup process will automatically be excluded.
                 */
                'exclude' => [
                    base_path('vendor'),
                    base_path('node_modules'),
                ],
 
                /*
                 * Determines if symlinks should be followed.
                 */
                'followLinks' => false,
            ],
 
        .......
 
        'destination' => [
 
            /*
             * The filename prefix used for the backup zip file.
             */
            'filename_prefix' => 'GIVE_PREFIX_HERE',
 
            /*
             * The disk names on which the backups will be stored.
             */
            'disks' => [
                'local',
            ],
        ],
    ],
 
    ......
 
        /*
         * Here you can specify the notifiable to which the notifications should be sent. The default
         * notifiable will use the variables specified in this config file.
         */
        'notifiable' => \Spatie\Backup\Notifications\Notifiable::class,
 
        'mail' => [
            'to' => 'YOUR_EMAIL_ADDRESS',
        ],
 
    ......
```

We are also passing a disks value as ‘local’. Doing so, our backup will stored in the `storage/app/Laravel` folder. We can also store our backups to external storage such as s3, Rackspace, SFTP, etc. These external storage settings require some additional steps to configure with Laravel filesystem. We will cover more about this in another future article. If you are looking for external storage then please read the Laravel [documentation.](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/filesystem)

then Open the terminal in your project root directory and run the command:

```
php artisan backup:run
```

and define this command in `app/Console/Kernel.php file`

like the following function

```
protected function schedule(Schedule $schedule)
{
    $schedule->command('backup:run')->daily()->at('06:00');
}
```

you can change time to backup as you want,

hopefully that help you.